# Activesheet.Shapes.AddPicture insert url image error

Tags: excel, vba

This specific URL I am getting errors:

```
Sub test()
Sheets(1).Shapes.AddPicture "https://mmecimage.cn/p/wxa5a434c1a89e7ebc/HGeDuiyxcqwFUcNsLHieLWLngEO5BJAbsWmNO4ieCyA" _
                          , msoFalse, msoTrue, 100, 100, 500, 600
End Sub
```

Thanks.

I tried other urls,other work,but this fail

Comment: See how that URL does not have something like `.jpg` or `.png` at the end? That means it's not a direct link to the image.

Comment: @braX - that doesn't mean the URL doesn't return an image though.  It may be an API which fetches an image from (eg) a database or folder and returns it in the response body.  As long as the body content is an image and the response has suitable a content-type header it should be fine.

Comment: Please share what error you are getting.